# Migrating/duplicating Content/Members from a Production site to Development

Tags: database, migration

(I don't feel this is a duplicate of "[Migrating between Development, Staging and Production for a pre-existing ExpressionEngine site](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/45/migrating-between-development-staging-and-production-for-a-pre-existing-express)" as I'm hoping it's much simpler/specific. Maybe it is a duplicate as I'm not familiar yet with all the nuances as the site is just getting started. If that's the case I would hope detail is provided before being marked as a duplicate. Moreover in the above no particular examples were given for migrating content.)

Assuming no new add-ons and thus tables have been added to either version, say I just want to grab new entries, members, and channel categories from production to development, is there a convenient way to do that? (And changes to existing entries/members or whatever other content?) Or do I just manually export/import from select tables via MySql (does this present problems?)?

Answer (score 5):

If you're just looking for a convenient way to transfer the latest data from one database to another (say from the production database into your development database) then [Navicat's](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql) data transfer feature is very handy. Though it accomplishes the same thing as the manual export/import you referred to, and will overwrite data not sync it, it's a lot more convenient. It allows you to choose the specific tables you want to transfer or to transfer all of them.

Navicat also lets you save transfer "profiles" for specific transfers you want to perform again so that they can be triggered with only a few clicks. It supports http tunneling as well, making it a handy tool for connecting to servers that do not provide SSH access.

Navicat has another feature that allows you to *sync* the data and/or structure of two databases. I have less experience with this (maybe another answer will address that), but it can be useful if used carefully.

Comment: that looks intersting, downloading trial version now.

Comment: Navicat's syncing works quite well, although it is important to be *careful* with it and check the advanced settings carefully. I'll see if i can write something up about it. Also about Imrie's new solution.

Comment: @adrienne I'd definitely be interested in hearing more of your thoughts on Navicat's sync feature. A write up would be awesome.

Comment: @adrienne got my vote for a write-up! =) Also, what did you mean by "Imrie's new solution"? Reference?

Comment: @notacouch [Site Manager](https://github.com/ckimrie/Site-Manager) by Chris Imrie. Demoed at EECI2012, its a module that provides ways to sync/move content/channels/fieldtypes/etc between environments. (among other things)