# Syncing channel data across servers

Tags: ee2, deployment

We typically have a dev/staging/production setup for sites. We have all the configuration stuff sorted out and deploying from one to another is easy.

The problem is the database, specifically channel data, which contains both structural and user contributed data. Is there a good way to sync channel data when new features are added to the site, without bringing the site down?

Comment: Hi cbad, and welcome to the site. Your question is pretty close to a duplicate of this question [Migrating/duplicating Content/Members from a Production site to Development](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/183/migrating-duplicating-content-members-from-a-production-site-to-development) and is also pretty similar to [Migrating between Development, Staging and Production for a pre-existing ExpressionEngine site](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/45/migrating-between-development-staging-and-production-for-a-pre-existing-express). Take a look at those perhaps

Comment: I did see that, and I had a further question (posed above). I added it there, but as an answer (my rep is too low to comment yet). Someone let me know you shouldn't pose a question in an answer, so I deleted it and re-asked it here. Hopefully others will benefit from the answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the closest thing we have to migrating content between servers. Unfortunately this is has always been an achilles heel of EE (and most CMSs for that matter).

https://github.com/ckimrie/Site-Manager