# Keeping content synced in development

Tags: development, workflow

Good Afternoon EE StackExchange,

I was wondering if anyone had experience keeping their development environment in sync with production content. The problem being that a content freeze is not permissable on long-term projects, and our client insist that they need to see the latest content from production. Is this matter of dumping specific tables from the database and moving them down to development. I've seen a few strategies, but all of them seemed overly manual and not in line with just moving content. To be short, I am looking for a strategy to move content from Production to development, after changes have been made to development (so overwriting the database is not an option). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You statement of:

> after changes have been made to development (so overwriting the
>   database is not an option)

Means it isn't straightforward, although it is possible, it's not easy. If you must create content on the Development server and move it to Production **and** there's no chance of Live being updated independently, then you can move the relevant tables up from Dev to Prod. If both can be updated then you'll have to duplicate stuff manually!

One alternative may be to consider using something like [Publisher](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher) or [Better Workflow](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/better-workflow), entering all the content into Production, but the client can see the draft content and the live content is then unaffected. And if there is still content that can only be reviewed on Dev, then it can be entered as draft on Prod and the database bought down to Dev.

As you make reference to, there are other questions that relate to this:

- [Migrating between Development, Staging and Production for a pre-existing ExpressionEngine site](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/45/migrating-between-development-staging-and-production-for-a-pre-existing-express/64#64)
- [How to deploy from localhost development server to live server?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/how-to-deploy-from-localhost-development-server-to-live-server)
- [Syncing channel data across servers](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/syncing-channel-data-across-servers?rq=1)