# Addon to "package" data like Channels, Addons, etc across sites

Tags: import, export

I have 2 installations of one site.

I have channels and addons that exist in one site but not in the other.

Is there an easy way or an addon that enables me to basically "export" the data from one of the sites to the other?

Comment: Two similar posts are ["Syncing channel data across servers"](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/syncing-channel-data-across-servers) and ["Migrating/duplicating Content/Members from a Production site to Development"](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/183/migrating-duplicating-content-members-from-a-production-site-to-development/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used this, but saw someone demoing it and it may be exactly what you are looking for: https://github.com/ckimrie/Site-Manager