# Duplicating a site to a subdomain (for development)

Tags: development, git

Just a quick question with regards to what people think is the best way to handle this situation.

I have a site set-up. When also have a duplicate of the site at a subdomain.

Well.. it was a duplicate, but I haven't kept things synchronised and it's basically fallen behind the live site.

I want to start some substantial development.

I presume I can duplicate all the content from the live site, back to the development subdomain? (Preferably automated as I wouldn't want to go through all the control panel changes again.)

OR

Can anyone suggest a better way to carry out development?

I have only ever worked via files > updating > push to site via FTP, but would love a better development environment. Can anyone suggest a better way, or some reading that is specific to EE development.

(p.s - I've never used GIT before :)

Cheers!

Comment: Other similar questions that have answers: [1](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/183/migrating-duplicating-content-members-from-a-production-site-to-development), [2](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/managing-database-for-single-site-across-multiple-servers), [3](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/183/migrating-duplicating-content-members-from-a-production-site-to-development)

Comment: My search skills failed me :( - Thank you for these. I shall do some reading!