# Adding new functionality to Live site while keep members

Tags: database

I have a live(Production) site, in which new users are signing up every day.

Meanwhile, I have a local version of this site on which I've built lots of new functionality. If I were to push the local DB live, then the newer members would be deleted.

Is there a way to import the new members into my Local site and then deploy?

Or would it be easier to migrate the new features into my Live site.  I am trying to avoid doing this manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, how much **new** functionality is there? You've already made a mistake if we're talking about multiple new addons and many different database tables. Just take it piecemeal; migrate one new feature in at a time. First, create and import the relevant database tables, then copy your addons over. After a complete production backup, try and go live with the new feature.

Ad nauseam. And if you have members tables full of new members in production, just don't copy over that data. And as usually kids, **back it up before you try anything**.

If you want a better answer, you'll have to be a lot more specific by what `new functionality` means in this context.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked many times and the best answer can be found [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/45/migrating-between-development-staging-and-production-for-a-pre-existing-express).

This is typical of many CMS's, where you should only be creating content on the live database. New add-ons etc should ideally be installed on live before you start utilising their functionality in templates, etc.

You should really be utilising external templates, so changes to these are stored in the database and therefore easily updated.

Even copying specific tables is risky if you have associated view tracking, editors on live, commenting, etc.

If you copy live members into your local, then on deployment, copy the local database to live, there's every chance that the live data could have been updated in the time it took you to copy it down, deploy and copy it up. It will also risk the live site being unavailable during the whole deployment.